# Hosting multiple .net core application on Ubuntu using Nginx

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, nginx, asp.net-web-api, hosting

I created sample web api on .net core and registered it on default file in Nginx and was able to access it from outside.
The API looked like https://<>/api/values.
Now I want to add more configurations to host more web api with different port number. The problem is how will default file differentiate between multiple APIs since base URL is same i.e localhost\<> for all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create server blocks. Each of these server blocks will handle/listen/respond to different app. You can host as many apps you want to on a single Ubuntu machine using nginx this way.

[This](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04) will be very helpful and describe the entire process of creating server blocks for your nginx server.